# What is the difference between a C# property with a getter and a property with an equals sign?

Tags: c#, properties, getter-setter

What is the difference between these two properties:

```
public int Foo = 6;
public int Bar {get;} = 6
```

Here is a link to a working program that shows the output is the same: https://replit.com/@TomDane/GloriousDramaticScope#main.cs

```
using System;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
      
      var someClass = new SomeClass();
      
      Console.WriteLine(someClass.PropertyWithEquals);
      Console.WriteLine(someClass.PropertyWithGetter);
      
    }
}

public class SomeClass {
    public int PropertyWithEquals = 6;
    public int PropertyWithGetter {get;} = 6;
}
```

The output of this is 6 and 6. If the output is the same, are there any other reasons to prefer one over the other?

Comment: The first is a field, not a property.

Comment: @juharr and what is the practical reason for choosing one over the other in this example? The first is a public field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In real life, the result might be the same, but the first one `Foo` can be set, so it's equal to `public int Foo {get; set;}` while `Bar` cannot be set outside the class and it's already initialized